# How do I sort an array of records by distance using geocoder on an associated model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-geocoder

Im on Rails 4 using geocoder to handle locations.

I have two models Listing and Location

**Listing**

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :locations
end
```

**Location**

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :listing
  geocoded_by :full_address
  after_validation :geocode

  def full_address
    [street, city, state, country].compact.join(", ")
  end
end
```

I trying to make a simple search function where a user types in a city and is returned back a list of listings that are within 50 miles of the search query.

I have my search functionality being handled in my listings controllers index action

```
def index
    @query = Geocoder.search(params[:q]).first
    @location = Location.near(@query.address, 50).order("distance")
    @listings = Listing.find(@location.map(&:listing_id))
end
```

I want the results returned to be ordered by distance to the city searched for. When I search, the results returned are ordered by the listing ids.

The only way Ive been able to make this work, was to do my @listings variable like so

```
def index
    @query = Geocoder.search(params[:q]).first
    @location = Location.near(@query.address, 50).order("distance")
    @listings = []
    @location.each do |l|
      @listings.push(Listing.find(l))
    end
end
```

But this runs a bunch of db query's and Im worried that with a lot of records and searches, there will be a lot of strain on the db.

Is there a more concise way of having the array ordered the way I want? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`ActiveRecord.find` takes an array and in that case does a single query. So if you can do `Listing.find` for an individual location then it's just as easy to do it for the whole array:

```
def index
  @query = Geocoder.search(params[:q]).first
  @location = Location.near(@query.address, 50).order("distance")
  @listings = Listing.find(@location)
end
```

That should then do three queries: the Geocoder search, the Location query, then the single Listing query.

(I wouldn't bother optimising it any more at this point.)

Comment: Thanks for the response,  but when I do your suggestion,  I get a " Can't visit location" error.

Comment: I don't know these classes exactly, maybe instead of `@location` try `@location.to_a`.

Comment: Not sure this will give you what you want. If `@location` contains Location records with ids [1, 3, 4, 12] `Listing.find(@location)` will return Listing records with those ids (i.e. [1,3,4,12]) rather than the records that belong to Location records [1,3,4,12].

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out a better way to sort my Listing array.

```
        @listings = Listing.find(@location.map(&:listing_id)).sort_by{|listing| listing.locations.first.distance_to(@query.address)}
```

Im probably going to run into problems in the future when I add the ability to have multiple locations per listing in the future, but this works for now and Ill cross that bridge wen I come to it,